# Django login with wrong credentials returns 200 not 401

Tags: python, django, http, http-status-codes

This is a pretty straight forward test, but I can't seem to get it right.

I want to check which users can login and perform actions (it's part of a larger suite of tests), but the very first step causes some issues.

```
class SuperUserTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.su = User.objects.create_superuser('super','','the_correct_password')
    def test_su_can_login(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
            {'username': 'super', 'password': 'the_wrong_password'})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,401)

        # Success redirects to the homepage, so its 302 not 200
        response = self.client.post(reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
            {'username': 'super', 'password': 'the_correct_password'})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,302)
```

When I run the test I get:

```
(my_app)00:20 ~/my_app (master)$ ./manage.py test my_app.SuperUserTest
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_su_can_login (my_app.SuperUserTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./my_app/tests.py", line 341, in test_su_can_login
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code,401)
AssertionError: 200 != 401

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 1.180s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

**Why is django returning HTTP code `200` when I incorrectly login?**

For additional context, here is how I'm managing the login/logout urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^accounts/login/?$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/?$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout',
        {'next_page': '/'}),
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's some debate in the web community about what the right response to a credentials failure is. For example, here's a [Wordpress ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25446) about switching from `200` to `401`. Here on Stack Overflow you can find [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32897804/2395796) recommending `200` and [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32752617/2395796) recommending `401`.

Django chooses to return a `200` response along with the re-rendered form.

In my opinion this is the right approach. A `401` or `403` response indicates that the user doesn't have permission to access the resource (URL). But in this case the resource is the login point, and you don't *need* credentials to access that; by definition it's available to all users. So essentially this case is no different from any other form validation—the server is checking the inputs it was sent, and if they're invalid it returns a `200` response along with the form and an error message.

Answer (score 3):

you can easily customise this behaviour with something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView


class LoginView(LoginView):
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        response = super().form_invalid(form)
        response.status_code = 401
        return response
```

and you will need to change the corresponding url:

```
    path("accounts/login/", views.LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
```

Comment: You are missing: ```template_name = 'admin/login.html'``` otherwise says login.html missing.

Comment: The LoginView view by default points to a template named "registration/login.html", so that, you can provide a template with that name. Else, if you use template_name = 'admin/login.html' you will use the admin login template that comes in the django package, but what is very basic. Or you can copy and modify that template, as mentioned in the Django tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had a look through the Django source code and the reason why is in [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L28) function after line `52`. If the form is invalid, the `login` view returns a `TemplateResponse`, simply returning to the same page and rendering the form with the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the error message returned to the user is found in `response.text`:

```
if 'Please enter a correct username and password' in response.text:
    # ...
```

In your case (unit test) you can probably use (not tested):

```
self.assertRegex(response.text, 'Please enter a correct username and password')
```

The only limit to this is if the error message changes in Django for some reason (that's why I'm not using the full message which is actually `Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.`).