# Django 1.7's admin reports failed logins as HTTP 200 instead of HTTP 403

Tags: python, django, django-admin

When I login to Django admin with an incorrect username and password combination it logs the event as an HTTP 200:

```
[10/Mar/2015 10:24:06] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.0" 200 2074
```

I would expect that it would be recorded as a 403.

`django.contrib.admin.forms.AdminAuthenticationForm` raises a `forms.ValidationError` if the login is invalid. Is there a way I could patch this functionality to return HTTP 403?

Comment: This isn't a bug...The server understood the request fine, and is returning a `200` with a response/message...i.e. "This was an incorrect login combo, but we have a response for you and this login template was properly returned for you again"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django login with wrong credentials returns 200 not 401](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839434/django-login-with-wrong-credentials-returns-200-not-401)