# What would be the correct HTTP response for a change password request where the old password entered is incorrect?

Tags: http, http-status-codes

In a change password request, if the old password is not right, what would be the correct response?

I'm thinking 401 Unauthorized? Or is it 400 Bad Request?

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit tricky because I think you can make the argument for either, and I also feel that `409` and `422` could be argued.

Ultimately I think that it's important to use a more specific HTTP status code, if a generic client can do something useful with the response. Because of this, I think it doesn't really matter in this case.

I think I would be tempted to *not* use 401, because I associate that close to the `Authorization` header, and you're probably not using it in this case.

`422`or `400` are the best. This is entirely based in opinion. Either of those indicate that there was something wrong with the request (`422` a bit more specific: there's nothing wrong with the format, but there is something wrong with the actual values sent to the server).

`409` is sometimes used to indicate that the current request is valid, but the current state of the server prevents it from being successful. Given that the current state of the server is "the current password was something else", `409` could be appropriate.

Ultimately I don't think any is *really* wrong, and it's not *really* important but my vote would go to `422` first, and `400` next.

Some sources (first few are mine, last link is from one of the authors of the http specification)

- https://evertpot.com/http/400-bad-request
- https://evertpot.com/http/422-unprocessable-entity
- https://evertpot.com/http/409-confict
- https://www.mnot.net/blog/2017/05/11/status_codes

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of site you're developing. If you're talking about a RESTful service than using a 4xx response code makes sense. See Evert's answer.

If you're talking about a password change form embedded in a web page, then the typical way to handle this—or any form validation failure—is to return `200` and show the error so the user can correct it. That's standard behavior in many web frameworks. (People do have [different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32897804/2395796) [opinions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32752617/2395796) about whether that's the best response to a login form, though.)

Comment: If the intent of the request is to change a password, then a 200 OK response suggests that that request was successfully completed.

Comment: True, i took this as a REST API.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry So let's say I'm a user trying to access some locked ressource, Will you send `HTTP Forbidden` because I'm trying to access something I have no right to or will you send `HTTP OK` with a different response/data structure than the one I'd get if I had acces to the ressource?

Comment: @AlexandreDaubricourt: I'm not sure how that's related, since in this case the user clearly has permission to access the password change page. In any case, I've edited the answer to clarify that I'm talking about standard form validation behavior, not a RESTful service.